# Schrödinger-Operator on $L^2[0,2\pi]$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, mathematical-physics

In Reed-Simon Analysis of Operators they often talk about operators like $H = - \Delta +V$ as an operator on $L^2[0,2\pi]$ (like in Theorem XIII 88. What do they mean by that? Or is their a canonical dense subset that is meant instead?-Of course, this operator is not well-defined on $L^2[0,2\pi]$, so what is their intention behind this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator should get you started.  In short, yes, the operator is really only defined on a dense subspace of $L^2$.  In general, there is no canonical choice of subspace, and this leads to a number of subtle issues.  The choice of domain for such an operator is often related to boundary conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking of a domain $\mathscr{D}(H)$ which is dense in $X=L^{2}$. So they really mean
$$
            H : \mathscr{D}(H) \subset X \rightarrow X.
$$
The domain $\mathscr{D}(H)$ is where the appropriate endpoint conditions are imposed. So the domain might be, for example, the space of twice absolutely-continuous functions $f$ on $[0,2\pi]$ for which $-f''+Vf \in L^{2}$ and such that $f(0)=f(2\pi)$. The more you restrict $H$, the larger the domain of the adjoint $H^{\star}$ becomes. You want to find just the right balance so that $H=H^{\star}$, meaning that both domains are identical (which is the meaning of selfadjoint for unbounded operators.) The Mathematical Foundations of Quantum Mechanics were first defined this way by John von Neumann in the 1930's, who also formulated and proved the Spectral Theorem for unbounded densely-defined selfadjoint linear operators on a complex Hilbert space.

Comment: I remember when I did Functional Analysis with mathematicians that we also discussed this space of twice abs-cont. functions. But then our lecturer told us, that in the context of differential equations Sobolev spaces are much more popular. Therefore, I was wondering whether there is also an appropriate Sobolev space for this example?

Comment: When working on the real line, the spaces you mentioned are the same; I prefer the classical definition when working on $\mathbb{R}$. Once you start working in higher dimensions, then a Sobolev Space is required, and there is no simple characterization in terms of classical notions. These spaces naturally arise in the process of trying to extend the graph of $H$ until it is closed, which is necessary in order to have $H=H^{\star}$.

Comment: It should be noted that the formalism of Quantum Mechanics directly determines the underlying spaces which must be 'reachable' through closure operations in order for all measurements to be approximated to a desired accuracy by starting with simple objects and applying finite numbers of operations. QM imposes a precise Mathematical structure, especially when it comes to free-space problems where there cannot be any additional required conditions (problems should be 'essentially selfadjoint'.) Restrictions of free-space functions are then used to study the QM problems on other domains.

Comment: so the Sobolev space I would have considered for the Hamiltonian in general would be $H^2([0,2\pi])$. Is there an example where this $H$ sobolev space might not be the right space?

Comment: There are times where you'll need to modify the domain so that $Hf$ stays in $L^{2}$, which is important for dealing with singular potentials. But the Sobolev spaces are appropriate starting points--especially for atomic Hamiltonians--because of the Laplacian. All of the non-relativistic atomic Hamiltonians are 'essentially selfadjoint' on the full space, which should be expected because there should be no conditions that can be imposed. So you can start with smooth functions or functions in Sobolev spaces, and the closure of the graph will give you something selfadjoint in free space.

Answer (score 1):

$L^2$ is nice because you have the inner product. What they probably mean is some Hilbert Space ($H^s =L^2$ such that $s$ derivatives make sense, note that this is just a very informal definition). So we have that $S = - \Delta + V$ acts as follows:

$$S:H^s \to L^2$$

Notice that if we're working with $H^s$ everything will make sense if $s\geq 2$ since we know that $\psi \in H^2 \implies \Delta \psi \in L^2$